# populating a combobox when modifying an object

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

I`ll try to be as straightfoward as posible. I have a list of clients on a datagridview and also I have a form that allows me to either add a new client or modify it. I have no problem when adding a new client but when modifying i cant find the way to fill some of the textboxes and the combobox. the combobox should show me the city and the textboxes should show me the address. the code is the following

```
 private void Modificar()
    {
        if (dgCliente.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        DataGridViewRow row = dgCliente.SelectedRows[0];
        Cliente cliente = (Cliente)row.Tag;


        tcClientes.SelectedTab = tpGeneral;
        //txtActividad.Text = cliente.Actividad;
        txtApellido.Text = cliente.Apellido;
        if (cliente.Categoria == Categoria.Cliente)
        {
            rbCliente.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            rbProveedor.Checked = true;
        }

        txtCelular.Text = cliente.Telefono.Celular;
        txtTelefonoComercial.Text = cliente.Telefono.TelComercial;
        txtTelefonoDeposito.Text = cliente.Telefono.TelDeposito;
        txtTelPart.Text = cliente.Telefono.TelPart;
        txtFax.Text = cliente.Telefono.Fax;
        txtRazonSocial.Text = cliente.RazonSocial;
        txtCodigo.Text = cliente.Id.ToString();
        txtContacto.Text = cliente.Contacto;
        txtEmail.Text = cliente.Email;
        cliente.CuentaCorriente = new CuentaCorriente();
        txtCuenta.Text = cliente.CuentaCorriente.NumeroCuenta;
        cliente.Domicilio = new Domicilio();
        //cliente.Domicilio.Localidad.CodigoPostal = new CodigoPostal();
        txtCalle.Text = cliente.Domicilio.Calle;
        cliente.Domicilio.Localidad = new Localidad();
        SeleccionarLocalidad(cliente.Domicilio.Localidad);
        txtDepto.Text = cliente.Domicilio.Departamento;
        txtNumero.Text = cliente.Domicilio.Numero;
        txtPiso.Text = cliente.Domicilio.Piso;

        cliente.Domicilio.Localidad = GetLocalidadSeleccionada();
        //cliente.Domicilio.Localidad.Provincia = new Provincia();
        //txtProvincia.Text = cliente.Domicilio.Localidad.Provincia.NombreProv;
        //cliente.Domicilio.Pais = new Pais();
        //txtPais.Text = cliente.Domicilio.Localidad.Pais.NombrePais;            
        cliente.Identificacion = new Identificacion();
        txtNroDni.Text = cliente.Identificacion.Dni;
        txtCuit.Text = cliente.Identificacion.Cuit;
        txtNroCuil.Text = cliente.Identificacion.Cuil;
        txtNroCi.Text = cliente.Identificacion.Ci;
        txtNroLc.Text = cliente.Identificacion.Lc;
        txtNroLe.Text = cliente.Identificacion.Le;
        txtNombre.Text = cliente.Nombre;
        txtObservaciones.Text = cliente.Observaciones;
        txtPagWeb.Text = cliente.PagWeb;
        //cliente.Sexo = new Sexo();
        //cliente.Sexo = GetSexoSeleccionado();
        //cliente.SituacionIva = new SituacionIva();
        //cliente.SituacionIva = GetSituacionAnteIvaSeleccionada();
        txtObservaciones.Text = cliente.Observaciones;

        btnModificarCliente.Enabled = true;
        btnAceptar.Enabled = false;
        tsbGuardar.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void SeleccionarLocalidad(Localidad localidad)
    {
        cbbLocalidad.SelectedItem = localidad;
    }
```

when modifying the client info the textboxes for the phone, celphone or fax are filled with the right data but the textboxes that should show the address (domicilio)
and the comboxbox that should show the city are not....I hope i was clear enough for you to understand my concern. Please help and thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

here is the cliente class

```
public class Cliente
    {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public string RazonSocial { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaIngreso { get; set; } 
    public Domicilio Domicilio { get; set; } // residencial
    public Domicilio DomicilioComercial { get; set; }
    public Domicilio DomicilioFiscal { get; set; } // para envio de facturas o tramites
    public Telefono Telefono { get; set; }
    public Telefono Celular { get; set; }
    public Telefono Fax { get; set; }
    public Telefono TelComercial { get; set; }
    public Telefono TelDeposito { get; set; }
    public string Contacto { get; set; }
    public SituacionIva SituacionIva { get; set; } // Si es resp. inscripto,monotributista o exento      
    public Identificacion Dni { get; set; }
    public Identificacion Cuil { get; set; }
    public Identificacion Cuit { get; set; }
    public Identificacion Lc { get; set; }
    public Identificacion Le { get; set; }
    public Identificacion Ci { get; set; }
    public ListaDePrecios ListaDePrecios { get; set; }
    public Vendedor Vendedor { get; set; }
    public string Actividad { get; set; }
    public Categoria Categoria { get; set; } // Si es cliente, provedor etc
    public Sexo Sexo { get; set; } // Masc o femenino        
    public string PagWeb { get; set; }
    public CuentaCorriente CuentaCorriente { get; set; }
    public string Observaciones { get; set; }
    public Identificacion Identificacion { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: Has the cbbLocalidad control been assigned a datasource and DisplayMember,ValueMember properties?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is right, but it seems like this is what your are asking. This method will allow you to insert text into the ComboBox cells that are in your datagrid.

```
    private void ChangeComboBoxCellItems(int RowIndex, int ColumnIndex,string TextToAdd)
    {
        //this line finds the correct row and cell
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell ComboBoxCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[ColumnIndex];

        //this line inserts the text into the combobox items
        ComboBoxCell.Items.Add(TextToAdd);

        //This sets the display text to the string you added to the combobox
        ComboBoxCell.Value = TextToAdd;
    }
```

Comment: ACTUALLY NO...when I add a new client using the clienteditorform I select the client city from the combobox and that info goes to a data base and to a datagridview that allows me to filter and modify a client. when adding everything is correct but when modifying I expect the clienteditorform to be filled with the client info so I can modify its data. most of the data is actually shown in the textboxes but the address and the city that shoud be filled automatically on the combobox it is not. thats my problem...thx